# Are blocks and libdispatch available on linux?

Tags: linux, libdispatch

I would love to try out grand central dispatch, but all I have to develop on is an Ubuntu workstation. Is libdispatch, and the blocks extension to c/obj-c etc... available on linux? If so, how do I get them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may need to use the LLVM [Clang (available on Ubuntu)](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/clang/2.8-0ubuntu2) compiler to get blocks at this time (I don't think this is available in gcc yet, but I haven't been keeping up with gcc, so I could be wrong.)

There are efforts underway to port [libdispatch (home for the open source libdispatch)](http://libdispatch.macosforge.org/trac/wiki) to Linux.  Most of the effort seems to be on Debian so far, but some on other distributions, too.  See these discussion threads:

- [linux + libdispatch + clang + blocks](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.macosx.libdispatch.devel/321)
- [libdispatch porting status update](http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.macosx.libdispatch.devel)
- [Grand Central Dispatch available for Debian](https://web.archive.org/web/20110511180826/http://blog.technologeek.org/2010/07/17/330) (archived link)

Comment: Thank you! Many google searches resulted in nothing but confusion for me.

Comment: You're welcome!  It can be surprisingly difficult to find stuff like this with Google at times, particularly on a subject that isn't familiar.

Comment: As long as you're ok using clang, I'm [using gcd quite happily](http://chris.mowforth.com/installing-grand-central-dispatch-on-linux) on ubuntu natty.

Answer (score 6):

I've done some work to get the OS X Mountain Lion version of libdispatch working on Linux; the result is up at Github: http://nickhutchinson.me/libdispatch/.

Answer (score 3):

Use clang-3.4.

- sudo apt-get install libdispatch-dev
- sudo apt-get install libblocks-runtime-dev
- Compile with -fblocks
- Link with -lBlocksRuntime -ldispatch

Answer (score -1):

Rather than use blocks, use c++ lambdas. They play better with c++ and there is less hidden magic.

I do it like this:

```
/// Dispatch a function object to a queue.
template<class F>
static void dispatch_async_function(dispatch_queue_t queue, F f) {
    struct context_t {
        using function_type = F;

        context_t(function_type&& f) noexcept
        : _f(std::move(f))
        {}

        static void execute(void* p) noexcept {
            auto context = reinterpret_cast<context_t*>(p);
            if (context) {
                try {
                    context->_f();
                }
                catch(...) {
                    // error processing here
                }
                delete context;
            }
        }

    private:
        function_type _f;
    };

    dispatch_async_f(queue, new context_t<F>(std::move(f)), &context_t<F>::execute);
}
```

And if you need to ensure that some shared resource exists before the call takes place (such as a callback on an object that is kept alive by a shared pointer):

```
/// Dispatch a function object to a queue. Only execute the function if the tie
/// locks successfully.
template<class F>
static void dispatch_async_tied_function(dispatch_queue_t queue, std::weak_ptr<void> tie, F f) {
    struct context_t {
        using function_type = F;

        context_t(function_type&& f) noexcept
        : _f(std::move(f))
        {}

        static void execute(void* p) noexcept {
            auto context = reinterpret_cast<context_t*>(p);
            auto lock = _tie.lock();
            if (context && tie) {
                try {
                    context->_f();
                }
                catch(...) {
                    // error processing here
                }
                delete context;
            }
        }

    private:
        function_type _f;
        std::weak_ptr<void> _tie;
    };

    dispatch_async_f(queue, new context_t<F>(std::move(f)), &context_t<F>::execute);
}
```

call them like this

```
dispatch_function(queue, []() { something(); });
```

or...

```
dispatch_tied_function(_myQueue, shared_from_this(), [this]() { somethingOnThis(); });
```

Comment: This is the reason I try to avoid C++ whenever I can. I have programmed C++ for some 25 years, but looking at your code I hardly get any mental image as to what it actually does. C++ used to be "C with classes" but this is a bit too weird.